# adding a list View inside a dialog

Tags: android, android-listview, dialog

i have a custom class CustomDialog
that has a show() function that should show a dialog with content from listview, dialog apears fine until i add the list part.

here is the XML code for elements_view:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lvElements"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/circuit_board" >
</ListView>
```

and here is the element_layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/circuit_board">
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    />

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

here is my CustomDialog class:

```
package com.example.control;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.example.control.R;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class CustomDialog {

private Context con;
    private Activity act;
ListView list;
    private ArrayList<String> listData;
static final String[] str = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
    "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwifruit",
    "Jackfruit", "Mango", "Olive", "Pear", "Sugar-apple" };

    CustomDialog(Activity activity) throws Exception{
this.act = activity;
this.con = activity;
}

    void show() throws Exception{
try{

       try{
 list = (ListView) act.findViewById(R.id.lvElements);


ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(con,R.layout.element_layout,str);
    list.setAdapter(ad);
    }
     catch(Exception ex){
 android.util.Log.e("Control", "problem in list ");
 android.util.Log.e("Control", ex.toString());

     }

     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(con);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.elements_view);
        final Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,         WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();
}
catch(Exception ex){
     throw ex;

}

   }


   }//ends the class
```

the inner try is causing the dialog not to show while getting this in logcat:

```
01-17 01:54:50.122: E/Control(29502): problem in list 
01-17 01:54:50.122: E/Control(29502): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 01:54:50.152: D/dalvikvm(29502): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3096K, 43% free 10009K/17364K,    paused 24ms, total 27ms
01-17 01:54:50.162: I/dalvikvm-heap(29502): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.203MB for       3464956-byte allocation
01-17 01:54:50.202: D/dalvikvm(29502): GC_CONCURRENT freed 18K, 36% free 13374K/20748K,     paused 5ms+2ms, total 42ms
01-17 01:54:50.272: D/AbsListView(29502): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-17 01:54:50.292: D/dalvikvm(29502): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3386K, 32% free  11922K/17368K, paused 2ms+15ms, total 36ms
01-17 01:54:50.302: D/AbsListView(29502): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-17 01:54:50.312: D/AbsListView(29502): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-17 01:54:50.352: D/AbsListView(29502): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity onCreate(), I assume you inflate something other than 'elements_view.xml' with setContentView.
In show(), you set 'list' by searching the Activity's view hierarchy for R.id.lvElements:

```
list = (ListView) act.findViewById(R.id.lvElements);
```

You Activity's layout does not contain R.id.lvElements so list is set to null, hence the Null Pointer Exception when you try to set the adapter on it.

Your list view is defined in elements_view.xml which you inflate as the dialog's view hierarchy. Move the setting and usage of list to a point after dialog.setContentView() and call findViewById() on dialog, not act:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.elements_view);
list = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lvElements);
```

Comment: thanks, putting the array adapter and listview after   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.elements_view); solved the first probelm. but then i had to use this constructor for the adapter ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) that solved everything !

Answer (score 1):

First of all you just need to `Inflate Dialog Layout` like below:

```
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Now, create `Dialog` object Globally:

```
Dialog main_dialog;
```

Now, inflate your `Dialog Layout View` and set to `Dialog`:

```
final View DialogView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.elements_view, null);

main_dialog = new Dialog(Splash.this,R.style.Theme_Dialog);

main_dialog.setContentView(DialogView);
```

Now, your list view is defined in `elements_view.xml` which you inflate as the dialog's view hierarchy. find listview from your DialogView

```
list = (ListView)DialogView.findViewById(R.id.lvElements);
```

And after set adapter or such thing.
Try this